# How do i build a release exe with DEV C++?

Tags: c++, release, dev-c++

I want to build the exe to work on another computer. I believe I have found the dll's the program needs and included them in the same directory with the application along with all the files the application loads when run. Put the folder in a USB tested it on my PC first and it ran, plugged the USB in the other computer and the application immediately terminates on execution on the other computer. There was no error of missing dll or of any kind, just an on and off. So i thought to try building the exe in release mode as i have done in the past with visual studio, but i cant seem to find any such build option in DEV c++. maybe thats not my problem though, any ideas for me?

Comment: Is it possible you switched from a 32-bit machine to a 64-bit machine and only had 32-bit DLLs or vice-versa?

Comment: Are you dynamically or statically linking the mscv runtimes? If you are set to dynamically link them, you will have to install the runtimes on the target machine before you will be able to run your program. You can find the redistributables online for your compiler.

Comment: according to dependency walker GPSVC.DLL i added to the folder which i found on my system32 folder, is x64 and everything else is running on x86. and if i just remove GPSVC.DLL it says its missing. So i guess i need a x86 version of GPSVC.DLL? what should i do? i doubt "googleing GPSVC.DLL" download will get me anywhere.

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++. It hasn't been updated for 8 years.

Comment: I have also tried with visual c++ 2010 express, the result was the same

Comment: What is gpsvc.dll needed for in the application? A short googling told me it's something regarding group policies. If I remember correctly the windows _home_ versions do not have this feature. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Try running your app under depends.exe (from the windows sdk). It will not only show you what DLL dependencies you have but it'll show them (attempting) to load dynamically if you run it under profiling. You could also try running procmon.exe from sysinternals very quickly on the target machine when you run your app.

Comment: the target computer is indeed a windows home edition, but if that is the problem i still dont know how to solve it. Like i said, i doubt trying to dl the dll will get me anywhere. and if i could, inst that dll gonna try to load other dlls that it wont have?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a 32-bit copy of gpsvc.dll, you could try obtaining it from an actual 32-bit version of Windows and then placing it with all the other dlls your application uses. However, it's a Windows provided dll, so I don't think you're really supposed to do that, and it might not end up working anyways. That is, 64-bit Windows might notice this and not let you load the DLL.

As for building a 'release exe', I don't think Dev C++ has the concept of Release or Debug build configurations the way that Visual Studio and many other IDEs do. What you can do is go to Project Options, then Compiler tab, then the Linker heading in the list below. If 'Generate debug information' is set to 'Yes', change it to 'No'. You can also set 'Strip Executable' to 'Yes' if you want, as well as turning on the various optimization settings under the 'Optimization' heading that is below 'Linker'.

Alternatively, you can take the makefile that is automatically generated by Dev C++ and alter it, saving it under a different file name, like 'my_project_release.win'. What you'd do is alter it to remove command line switches like -g, -g3 or other similar flags that enable the inclusion of debugging information in a compiled binary. To strip symbols from the compiled binary, add -s to the CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS makefile variables in the same way the debug info flags were removed from the makefile. After creating this new makefile, go into your Project Options dialog box again, and go to the Makefile tab. Check 'Use Custom Makefile...' and then specify the location of this new makefile there, and you should be building a Release version of your executable now. To switch back to a Debug conversion, change the makefile line to point back to the original copy of the makefile that had the debug settings specified in it.

Comment: I tried moving the project to visual c++ 2010 express and build in release mode, but the result on the other computer was the same. I have tried playing with various debug and optimization options in the project options as well, still has the same result on the other computer.

Comment: Have you tried moving the exe and dlls to a folder on the actual computer away from the USB drive? I'm wondering if maybe the computer has some kind of permissions policy that prevents running programs from removable media like USB flash drives. You'll also want to see if the program's code loads DLLs explicitly or implicitly (if it has LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx calls in it, it's explicit). If it's using explicit loading, it could just be failing out due to program logic silently. In my experience, implicit link failures usually end up with Windows indicating which dll couldn't be loaded.

Comment: yes i also tried moving it onto the actual computer, but the result is the same. How do i check how the program loads dlls? do i set that in visual studio?

Comment: If you're just using function calls as they appear in the dlls' header files, it's implicit loading. e.g. if foo.dll exports void foo1(int); and int foo2(void); and you're calling foo1 and foo2 directly, it's likely doing implicit loading. If you find the strings 'LoadLibrary' or 'GetProcAddress' in the code, it's explicit loading. What you can do, if feasible, is run a debug version of the exe on the target computer and use remote debugging via Visual Studio to try and see which of your dlls are loading, if any. This will be indicated in the Output window under the 'Debug' category.

Comment: so if its explicit loading that might be the problem is what you are saying? if so, what action should i take to fix it? 
if i run a debug mode on VS on the target machine, that would mean installing and setting up visual studio on the target machine, which in my experience, would make the target machine no different from my machine and it would work. I can see which dlls are loading from my machine, but idk what dlls are for visual studio and debugging and which are for my exe. which got me to the "dependency walker" walker part. which makes it seem like i need a 32bit version of GPSVC.DLL

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (or click object properties in project bar, icon is like a shield).

Then go to:

Compiler > Linker > Generate debugging information (-g3)

and set it "no".

Just use devc+++ and enjoy!